# What is the difference between `>` (redirection) and Out-File in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have found comparisons of `>` against `Set-Content`, and of `Set-Content` against `Out-File`, but I have not found any description of how `>` and `Out-File` differ in PowerShell.

The "about redirection" document currently states,

> Typically, you use the Out-File cmdlet when you need to use its parameters...

... which leads me to believe that they are the same, that `>` is preferred because it is concise, but that `| Out-File` is necessary in some cases because `>` does not take parameters.

Is this a correct interpretation, or are there differences in the runtime behavior of these two methods of redirection?  For example, is `>` more efficient because `| Out-File` has the extra overhead of pipe and commandlet abstractions?  Does `>` have any difference in default settings for the sake of backwards compatibility with DOS or Unix `>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this a correct interpretation

## Yes, spot on!

When you use `... > $path`, PowerShell indeed executes `... | Out-File -Filepath $path` in the background.

When you use `... >> $path`, PowerShell simply adds the `-Append` switch.

This is evident from the source code of the current (version 7.0) [implementation](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/9212aac0fa020b657454ef4f9ff2fdd6fc6d759c/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/runtime/Operations/MiscOps.cs#L1155-L1212), and has been the case at least back to version 3.0 (and, I presume, 1 and 2)